# Needed clarification on infinite direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

While reading Liviu Nicolaescu "Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds" I came accross the notation, I'm not sure how to interpret. Hopefully, someone from this community will help to clarify things.

Let $E, F$ be two vector spaces over the field $R$. Consider the (infinite) direct sum
$$T(E,F)=\bigoplus_{(e,f)\in E\times F}R.$$

I know what the direct sum of vector spaces is, but in this case I'm not sure how to interpret the infinite direct sum as is written above. I probably would be able to imagine the infinite sum $\bigoplus E\times F$.
Could someone explain me what is the meaning of the above infinite sum?

Comment: I suspect that he really means that space of sequences $(r_{e,f})_{(e,f)\in E\times F}$ for which only finitely many of the elements in the sequence are non-zero.  But it is a strange thing he is doing, and I would have to see the context to figure out if it meant anything other than this.

Comment: My interpretation would be the vector space of functions $E\times F\rightarrow R$ such that they are zero at all except finitely many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given a family $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ of vector spaces, the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I} V_i$ consists of all families $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ with $v_i\in V_i$ for all $i\in I$, and such that $v_i=0$ for all but a finite number of $i$. In this case, $V_i=R$ for all $i$, and $I=E\times F$.